# @RequestBody is not working in spring boot with post html

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, post

I have tried to recieve in Spring boot from a post made in html, but in java when i use the @RequestBody the variable is empty. i tried with differentes methods but i cant receive the body of the post.

i tried with
@RequestParam

With those @, i received error Unsupported Media Type
@RequestBody MultiValueMap<String, String>
@RequestParam MultiValueMap<String, String>

This is my code

In the front i have this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
     <form  id="diagnosticoForm2" action="http://devlocal1.mx.att.com:7003/pruebaRequest?param1=123" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="requestBody" id="requestBody">
        <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="enviar"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

In the back i have this

```
    @POST
    @Path(value = "/pruebaRequest")
    @Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    public Response pruebaRequest(@QueryParam("param1") String param1, @RequestBody String requestBody
    ) throws JsonProcessingException, URISyntaxException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        
        System.out.println("Param 1: ".concat(param1));
        System.out.println("Request Body: ".concat(requestBody));
.
.
.
.
```

The result of println

Param 1: 123

Request Body:

[image: Result of print]

My json request: {"codigo": "10", "mensaje": "Error en el api"}

[image: Post in front]

[image: Details]

[image: Post request]

I want to receive the body in Spring boot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" means that the data in the request body is URL-encoded form data, not JSON-formatted data. Therefore, the @RequestBody annotation cannot be used to receive the data in the request body.

If you want to receive URL-encoded form data, you should use the @FormParam annotation instead of the @RequestBody annotation. Modify the code as follows:

```
@POST
@Path(value = "/pruebaRequest")
@Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
public Response pruebaRequest(@QueryParam("param1") String param1, @FormParam("requestBody") String requestBody
) throws JsonProcessingException, URISyntaxException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    
    System.out.println("Param 1: ".concat(param1));
    System.out.println("Request Body: ".concat(requestBody));
}
```